# filter by price based on product category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing site in WordPress using woo-commerce

I want to achieve the functionality that on single page price will be displayed by counting 50% discount on single product page

I had implemented the below code, it is working nicely on the simple products but not working on variable product

Please help me how can I achieve the custom price filtering on variable product
OR suggest me which filter to used to variable products

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'custom_price_WPA111772', 10, 2);

function custom_price_WPA111772($price, $product) {
    global $product;
    $pid = get_the_ID();
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) return $price;

        if( has_term( 'sale', 'product_cat' ,$product->ID) || has_term( 'Gift Ideas', 'product_cat' ,$product->ID)) 
        {
            $price = $price;
        }
        else
        {
            $price = $price * 50 / 100;
        }
    return $price; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer why my variable product is not showing custom price 
i added this in function.php and its works 
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);

```
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {

    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $pav){
        $def=true;
        foreach($product->get_variation_default_attributes() as $defkey=>$defval){
            if($pav['attributes']['attribute_'.$defkey]!=$defval){
                $def=false;             
            }   
        }
        if($def){
            $price = $pav['display_price'];         
        }
    }   
    return woocommerce_price($price);

}
```